# Why is the fire not rendering when sphere (domain) in viewport is hidden?

Tags: animation, physics, light, fire

The actual question is basically what I'm asking.

The Sphere is the domain so the fire and other animations will be contained within it. I would like to hide this sphere for a much more realistic appearance to the scene, yet when the domain is hidden and I hit playback there is no fire animation, not even a flash. I also have the issue when switching between rendering modes.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the fire as a object, and think of the domain as the renderer ~ you will not be able to see the fire without the domain. You can just bake the cache if it lags too much on raw playback.